# PHP Echoing ? instead of single quote from mssql nvarchar

Tags: php, sql-server

In SQL 2008, in a nvarchar type column I have a string, "Connects students’ prior knowledge, life experiences, and interests in the". When I look at the string in the database it looks correct. When I echo that string in php it returns, "Connects students**?** prior knowledge, life experiences, and interests in the". It replaces the single quote with a question mark. Can someone please explain why that is happening?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

EDIT:
PHP Source File Encoding: UTF-8 
SQL Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
Web page encoding: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Differences between character encodings?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. How could I confirm this?

Comment: DB encoding <-> PHP source file encoding <-> encoding of the web page you're echoing at

Comment: Did you set charset using: `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');`? Some answers here might be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322421/php-sql-server-how-to-set-charset-for-connection

Comment: @piotrekkr Where would you suggest I put that ini_set? Would that go in my mssql query class, or on the page that is displaying the text?

Comment: @Havelock Check my edit for the types of encoding happening in my code.

Comment: @Nathan `collation` and `character set` are [two different things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly/)

Comment: @Nathan If you use utf8 application wide then I think that best place to use `ini_set()` it is in your bootstrap code, probably in `index.php`. It must be set before connecting to mssql.