# SQL Server and Returning '???' Chinese in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode

I am running SQL Server 2008R2 and have a table.column with a mix of latin and Chinese characters. Here is an example; **'Admissions Department - 招生办'** the data type is set to 'nvarchar' (I've also tried ntext with no luck). 
Running PHP 5.4, I can't seem to get the text to display correctly. 
 Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT dbo.R_visitor_signin_departments.id,
dbo.R_visitor_signin_departments.department_name,
dbo.R_visitor_signin_departments.employee_id,
dbo.R_visitor_signin_departments.campus_id
FROM dbo.R_visitor_signin_departments
```

When I run the query and echo 'department_name' I get: **Admissions Department - ???**

My collation is set to Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Comment: Are the values stored correctly in the database? are you sure you're using UTF-8 encoding when printing? try, under PHP, `mysql_set_charset("utf8");`(use similar functions according to the sql library you're using) (for the DB) and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` (for the output)

Comment: I'm using a SQL Server (mssql) not mysql

Comment: check this out then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377812/getting-data-with-utf-8-charset-from-mssql-server-using-php-freetds-extension and, if it still doesn't help, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322421/php-sql-server-how-to-set-charset-for-connection