# Overcoming PHP/SQL Server encoding inconsistency

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, centos, odbc

Following [this blog](http://dominik.szynk.net/centos-6-x-and-microsoft-sql-server-odbc-linux-driver/#comment-21348) post, I managed to connect to a MSSQL Server form PHP/CentOS machine. I can get result, however I can not use comparison in the `where` clause. I should be due to different encoding. Here is my code:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:USERS", "username", "password");
$sql = "SELECT top 1 name FROM user where name='تست'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);
```

Also using `$name = mb_convert_encoding('تست', 'utf16');` (also 'UCS-2LE' encoding)  Was not helpful. How config PHP/MSSQL to use a single encoding?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set encoding like this: `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: This might be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322421/php-sql-server-how-to-set-charset-for-connection